# Magento 2 : Search query in magento search terms

Tags: magento2, template, search, search-terms

What is Search Query On Magento search terms?

How it affect the website ?

I have over 3 million query on my website a lot of them have nothing to do with what I sell ?

Do i need to delete it from my search query ?

Comment: Hi Cathy! Welcome to Magento SE ! It is not clear what you are referring to , are you referring to search terms located in magento;s admin marketing->seo section ?

Comment: It Is in the search term

Comment: Did you check my answer? DId it help?

Comment: I do not want to save search terms in which have zero search results.
Is there any solution ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148999)

Answer (score 0):

> What is Search Query On Magento template?

Search query in search terms table in admin are the searches done by customers/guests on your website.

> How it effect the website ?

The queries listed in search terms table are showed to other customers/guests when they type something similar. The more times some term is searched, the higher is it's probability of being shown and order in which it shown.

> I have over 3 million query on my website a lot of them have nothing to do with what I sell ? Do i need to delete it from my search query ?

If a search term don't return anything or return something you don't want it return then you can clear it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we are facing the same issue on magento site, my site also having a lot of search terms and they don't have any connection or similar, I guess is someone using our site to do SEO as well, I would suggest to clear and find a way to block this matter